Looker Studio: Time series chart bug when a custom filter is in use
I am experiencing a bug with the time series chart when trying to filter for brand/non-brand keywords.
I created a group in the Google Search Console data source (see screenshot "field" attached) and am using this as a filter: field
When I try to analyze the last 15 months without the query filter in use, everything is fine (see screenshot "without_filter" attached): without_filter
But when I am using the filter (either "brand" or "non-brand"), somehow the chart is cut off after 217 days (see screenshot "with_filter" attached): with_filter
Is anybody experiencing similar problems? I also tested the filter with tables and everything is fine, but for some reasons the charts are not displayed correctly when such a filter is in use.
